# Invalid outline number while reading tasks from Microsoft Project - After June Update of Microsoft Project?

Tags: mpxj

we are using MPP14Reader to read tasks from Microsoft Project, and recently for some of the projects, we are seeing that getOutlineNumber is giving wrong value. (ex: in Microsoft Project OutlineNumber is 1.2 ,
where as task.getOutlineNumber() is resulting in 2.4).

```
going through MPXJ code, found that this has been fixed in latest release via commit https://github.com/joniles/mpxj/commit/628df2b4a9dc4f00f59c5d8ad1c54648292a5c41
```

looking at commit description, seems this is happening after Microsoft June Update !!

do we have any workaround here ? can some one please help

Not all projects have this issue, seems to be issue with some of the projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue with MPXJ was recently fixed, as discussed here: https://github.com/joniles/mpxj/issues/107